How do I format markdown chatgpt response in tkinter frame python?
Chatgpt sometimes responds in markdown language. Sometimes the respond contains ** ** which means the text in between should be bold and ### text ### which means that text is a heading. I want to format this correctly and display it properly in tkinter. If it's bold or a heading, it should be formatted to bold or to a heading in tkintter. How to do this?
My code:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime
import openai
import json
import requests


history = []
# Create a function to use ChatGPT 3.5 turbo to answer a question based on the prompt
def get_answer_from_chatgpt(prompt, historyxx):
    global history

    openai.api_key = "xxxxxxx"
    append_to_chat_log(message="\n\n\n")
    append_to_chat_log("Chatgpt")

    print("Trying")

    messages = [
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
        ]

    try:
        stream = openai.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=messages,
            stream=True,
            
        )
        
        for chunk in stream:
            chunk = chunk.choices[0].delta.content
            chunk = str(chunk)
            if chunk != "None":
                append_to_chat_log(message=chunk)
        
        
        append_to_chat_log(message="\n\n\n")
        print("Streaming complete")
               
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request."

# Create a function to use OpenAI to answer a question based on the search results

def append_to_chat_log(sender=None, message=None):
    chat_log.config(state="normal")
    if sender:
        chat_log.insert("end", f"{sender}:\n", "sender")
    if message:
        chat_log.insert("end", message)
    chat_log.config(state="disabled")
    chat_log.see("end")
    chat_log.update()


def send_message(event=None):
    global history
    message = message_entry.get(1.0, "end-1c") 
    message = message.strip()
    message_entry.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    message_entry.update()
    
    if not message:
        pass 
    else:
              
        append_to_chat_log("User", message)
        history.append(("user", message))
        if len(history) >4:
            history = history[-4:]
        print(message)
        response = get_answer_from_chatgpt(message, history)
        
        history.append(("assistant", response))

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("Chat")

# Maximize the window
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)

chat_frame = tk.Frame(root)
chat_frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

chat_log = tk.Text(chat_frame, state='disabled', wrap='word', width=70, height=30, font=('Arial', 12), highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
chat_log.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(500,0), pady=10)

message_entry = tk.Text(root, padx=17, insertbackground='white', width=70, height=1, spacing1=20, spacing3=20, font=('Open Sans', 14))
message_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(500, 0), pady=(0, 70))  # Adjust pady to move it slightly above the bottom
message_entry.mark_set("insert", "%d.%d" % (0,0))
message_entry.bind("<Return>", send_message)

root.mainloop()


This question is similar to: How to show markdown formatted text in tkinter?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Seems like I’ve got to fix this manually by getting every streamed message and checking if  ** exists and then bold everything until it finds the closing **. Same for headings. The similar question linked in the comment section is very outdated and the library no longer exists.

The solution provided by idbrii in the linked question is an example you can reference.

I solved my own question
import tkinter as tk
from datetime import datetime
import openai

history = []

# Create a function to use ChatGPT 3.5 turbo to answer a question based on the prompt
def get_answer_from_chatgpt(prompt, historyxx):
    global history

    openai.api_key = "xxxx"
    append_to_chat_log(message="\n\n\n")
    append_to_chat_log("Chatgpt")

    print("Trying")

    messages = [
            {"role": "user", "content": prompt}
        ]

    try:
        stream = openai.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=messages,
            stream=True,
        )
        
        buffer = ""
        heading =  ""
        bold = False
        while True:
            chunk = next(stream)
            chunk = chunk.choices[0].delta.content
            chunk = str(chunk)
            if chunk != "None":
                buffer += chunk
                if "**" in buffer:
                    while "**" in buffer:
                        pre, _, post = buffer.partition("**")
                        append_to_chat_log(message=pre, bold=bold)
                        bold = not bold
                        buffer = post
                if "###" in buffer:
                    while "###" in buffer:
                        pre, _, post = buffer.partition("###")
                        append_to_chat_log(message=pre, bold=heading)
                        heading = not heading
                        buffer = post
                else:
                    append_to_chat_log(message=buffer, bold=bold)
                    buffer = ""
        
        append_to_chat_log(message="\n\n\n")
        print("Streaming complete")
               
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request."

def append_to_chat_log(sender=None, message=None, bold=False, heading=False):
    chat_log.config(state="normal")
    if sender:
        chat_log.insert("end", f"{sender}:\n", "sender")
    if message:
        if bold:
            chat_log.insert("end", message, "bold")
        if heading:
            chat_log.insert("end", message, "heading")
        else:
            chat_log.insert("end", message)
    chat_log.config(state="disabled")
    chat_log.see("end")
    chat_log.update()

def send_message(event=None):
    global history
    message = message_entry.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    message = message.strip()
    message_entry.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    message_entry.update()
    
    if not message:
        pass 
    else:
        append_to_chat_log("User", message)
        history.append(("user", message))
        if len(history) > 4:
            history = history[-4:]
        print(message)
        response = get_answer_from_chatgpt(message, history)
        history.append(("assistant", response))

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Chat")

# Maximize the window
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)

chat_frame = tk.Frame(root)
chat_frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

chat_log = tk.Text(chat_frame, state='disabled', wrap='word', width=70, height=30, font=('Arial', 12), highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
chat_log.tag_configure("sender", font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'))
chat_log.tag_configure("bold", font=('Arial', 12, 'bold'))
chat_log.tag_configure("heading", font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
chat_log.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(500,0), pady=10)

message_entry = tk.Text(root, padx=17, insertbackground='white', width=70, height=1, spacing1=20, spacing3=20, font=('Open Sans', 14))
message_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(500, 0), pady=(0, 70))  # Adjust pady to move it slightly above the bottom
message_entry.mark_set("insert", "%d.%d" % (0,0))
message_entry.bind("<Return>", send_message)

root.mainloop()


